# Django can't find swf file when using Tabletools

Tags: django, flash, tabletools

`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf 404 (NOT FOUND)`

That's the error! Here's the structure of my static files:
[image].

In "js" folder is where I put my Tabletools,"swf" contains the swf files. Here's the snippet of the settings in `dataTables.tableTools.js`

```
TableTools.DEFAULTS = {
    "sSwfPath":        "../swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
    "sRowSelect":      "none",
    "sRowSelector":    "tr",
    "sSelectedClass":  null,
    "fnPreRowSelect":  null,
    "fnRowSelected":   null,
    "fnRowDeselected": null,
    "aButtons":        [ "copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf", "print" ],
    "oTags": {
        "container": "div",
        "button": "a", // We really want to use buttons here, but Firefox and IE ignore the
                         // click on the Flash element in the button (but not mouse[in|out]).
        "liner": "span",
        "collection": {
            "container": "div",
            "button": "a",
            "liner": "span"
        }
    }
};
```

When I tried replacing the path with CDN of the swf file, there was no error but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please check your settings for STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL. Files as CSS, JS etc. should be placed in the static files folder, and accessing them is done using the STATIC_URL (something like www.domain.com/static/css/myfile.css).

Comment: Yah, my JS, CSS files are working, the only problem is I can't get the swf file.

Comment: Did you check file permissions? If folders are okay, it's a permission problem.

Comment: But what is your STATIC_URL? You're requesting your swf files via /swf, but presumably your CSS etc are requested via /static/css.

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`